# Code not executing?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a simple extension for Google Chrome that should collect data from you with a variable and prompt, and then should print what you inputted with document.write(variable_name);

Upon entering the code into the prompt, it does not print it.
I know the code is right, it works if I paste it into console, just not as an extension
How do I fix this?

```
var variable_name = prompt("Enter something");
document.write(variable_name);
```

Comment: Can you post your code, please?

Comment: "Code not executing" is the worst title I've seen all month.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided anywhere near enough context, but I'm going to toss out a theory here:

You're probably running that code in your extension's background page. If that's the case, you'd have an entry something like this in your `manifest.json`:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

Background code is executed on its own thread, with its own DOM. It can *not* interact with the current page. What you need is a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html). You'll make an entry in `manifest.json` that describes what pages you want it to be injected into. If you'd like to inject your code into *every* page, you can use `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]`. Otherwise, see [this page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) for help with creating a pattern (of set of patterns) to match the page(s) you want.

...or maybe I'm completely wrong, and you're already using a content script. If that's the case, please provide your entire `manifest.json` and any other code that's used in your extension.